# Reading .mat file in R

Tags: r, matlab, mat-file

I am unable to parse a list of values read from `a.mat` file.

```
library('rmatio')
eyes_open <- read.mat('Documents/TE/Implementation/DP23EyesOpen.mat')
print(str(eyes_open))
```

Running the script above produces:

```
$ mat1: num [1:30, 1:2000] -0.567 -0.54 -0.356 -0.43 -0.274 ...
NULL
```

I need a 30x2000 matrix, but I'm not sure how to get it from this list.

Comment: seems like it would be `eyes_open$mat1` ?

Comment: Yes. got it. Thanks.